# Does ImmutableJS skip unused code block?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I am playing around with Immutable.js code and noticed something funky.
Does Immutable.js skip code that saves to variables that won't be used?

```
const Immutable = require('immutable')

function transformErrors(errors) {
    let key = errors.keySeq()
    let mapped = key.map((v, keystr) => {
      console.log(v, keystr)
      return keystr
    })
  // If I enable the console log below, console log above works
  // console.log('mapped', mapped) 
};
const result = transformErrors(Immutable.fromJS([1, 2]));
```

For the above code, if

```
console.log('mapped', mapped)
```

is disabled, the mapping code doesn't get called.
I looked through the documentation but couldn't find any remarks on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line: `let key = errors.keySeq()` will return a `Seq` object, which in immutable.js is lazy.

The documentation provides the following details (https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Seq):

> **Seq is lazy** — Seq does as little work as necessary to respond to any method call. Values are often created during iteration, including implicit iteration when reducing or converting to a concrete data structure such as a List or JavaScript Array.
>   For example, the following performs no work, because the resulting Seq's values are never iterated:
>
> ```
> const { Seq } = require('immutable')
> const oddSquares = Seq([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ])
>   .filter(x => x % 2 !== 0)
>   .map(x => x * x)
> ```

So in your example, immutable.js isn't going to actually evaluate your map function until `mapped` is used somewhere.